# Visual Studio 2017 Cordova CORS still using xhr_proxy for API Post

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2017, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I have the following jquery post call in my Apache Cordova project created using the template in Visual Studio 2017.

```
$.post("http://localhost:58998/api/product/save", productData)
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

I run the project in Visual Studio 2017 in Debug mode to Android with Simulated to Nexus 4 option

[image]

However I get the browser error

> POST http://localhost:4400/xhr_proxy?rurl=http%3A//localhost%3A58998/api/product/save 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

From what I understand the xhr_proxy gets injected because it doesn't like me calling a different domain

I read you have to install the cordova-plugin-whitelist and adjust the config.xml

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

I added

```
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

just to try get it work without the xhr_proxy but this still gives the same error

How can I do an API post using jquery and be able to debug using a Visual Studio 2017 Android debugging?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a way to make it work?